# VBA Run time error 438: Export to PDF works for me, not for friend

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, runtime-error

I use VBA in EXCEL to fill a word document with bookmarks.
At the end I would like to create and save a pdf of this word document.

I used this line:

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat2 ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName & ".pdf", 17
```

It works for me, but for a friend she receives Runtime error 438.
I am using MS office 365, she uses MS office 2019.
Do you know how to make this line working for her also?

Looking forward to your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `2`.

Answer (score 1):

`Document.ExportAsFixedFormat2` is not supported for older versions. However, `Document.ExportAsFixedFormat`, is.

Thus, removing the ‘2’ should fix the issue:

```
 .ExportAsFixedFormat ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName & ".pdf", 17
```

Comment: My mistake, I see it now after scimming through the documentation. Anyhow, as you mentioned in the comment, removing the ‘2’ is the way to go for Excel @BigBen.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to maintain compatibility with different versions you can try the following...

```
wordVersion = Application.Version
If wordVersion > 15 Then
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat2 _
            'followed by parameters
else
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            'followed by parameters
end if
```